# Names formatting within for loop

Tags: python, pypy

I am trying to improve my existing code, **is there any way to affect multiples different variables without using dict or lists or tuples??**
I am trying to write something like:

```
number1 = 1
number2 = 2
number3 = 3

for i in (1,2,3):
    number{i} += 1
```

and then have number1 = 2 number2 = 3 and number3 = 4

i was thinking about formatting string but it doesn't work, thx for reading.

Comment: because this is a simple example with numbers. i am actually doing things with objects of a class i created, theses objects are getting values from sql selects statements, and i affect 1 object for each row

Comment: huh? just iterate over the rows to affect 1 object for each row - if you can use an index, use lists, if you can use a fetched value from the data, use a dictionary

Comment: By avoiding dicts, lists, and tuples, you're making your code *worse*, not better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach here would be to use dictionary :

```
In [26]: numbers={'number1': 1,
   ....:          'number2' : 2,
   ....:           'number3' : 3}

In [27]: for i in (1,2,3):
   ....:         numbers['number'+str(i)]+=1
   ....: 

In [28]: numbers['number1']
Out[28]: 2

In [29]: numbers['number2']
Out[29]: 3

In [30]: numbers['number3']
Out[30]: 4
```

otherwise you can also you `globals()`:

```
In [31]: number1 = 1

In [32]: number2 = 2

In [33]: number3 = 3

In [34]: for i in (1,2,3):
   ....:     globals()['number'+str(i)]+=1
   ....:     
   ....:     

In [35]: number1
Out[35]: 2

In [36]: number2
Out[36]: 3

In [37]: number3
Out[37]: 4
```

Comment: globals() will return a dictionary

Comment: how does it work from within a class? globals()['self.number'+str(i)]+=1 ?

Comment: @kingpin inside class you can use `locals()`.

Comment: @deathApril that's what I was thinking, I don't think there's any other way of doing this.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary there doesn't need to be other way, this is exactly what dictionaries are for

Comment: locals()['number' + x] += Info['Value']
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'str' and 'int'   

I think i will not be able to make it work this way, ty for help tho

Comment: @kingpin `x` is  an integer use `str(x)` , `locals()['number' + str(x)`]`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: you can't change `locals()` the same way you can `globals()` -- there's no promise that you'll see the results of your change.

Comment: yes str cast of course lol. I tried it but actually setattr(self, 'number%' % i, +=1) is more what I am looking for, still i can't find the right synthax to add 1

Answer (score 3):

You can access variables via a string representation of their name by using the dictionaries returned either [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) or [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) as appropriate - although you may find things don't behave as you expect if you modify the `locals()` dictionary, as noted in the docs and demonstrated by a code snippet at the bottom of this answer. You can also modify instance, class, or module variables via string labels by using, respectively, `setattr(self, 'some_variable_name', value)`, `setattr(ClassName, 'some_variable_name', value)` or `setattr(ModuleName, 'some_variable_name', value)` where self, ClassName and ModuleName are respectively references to a class instance, a class, and a module. Finally, you could always achieve what you want by using `exec` to execute code contained in strings. For example:

```
for i in range(5):
    temp = i
    exec('var%d = temp' % i)
print var0, var1, var2, var3, var4
```

will print `0 1 2 3 4`.

*But why on earth would you want to do any of these things?* You can just create and use a dictionary instead if you need to map arbitrary strings to values. If, as in your example, you're not dealing with arbitrary strings but rather with a sequence of variables that differ only by an integer index at the end of their name, then *use a list* because *that's what lists are for.*

Doing things in any of the ways I described in my first paragraph is confusing and pointless and I've never seen it done in real code.

I want to re-emphasize that the important thing here, as Ashwini Chaudhary has already pointed out, is that there is *no reason* to refer to variables via strings in this way because if you need to map strings to values, you can simply use a dictionary - which is exactly what you're indirectly doing anyway if you use `globals()` or `locals()`, since those functions each return dictionaries.

---

Anyway, as a postscript, I mentioned that things don't quite work right if you modify the locals() dictionary, which is not meant to be modified as noted in the docs, which remark

- `Note The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.`

Well, here is an illustration of that point, and may it deter anyone from trying this approach:

```
var1 = 'asdf'
def test1():
    var1 = 'ghjkl'
    print globals()['var2']
    print locals()['var2']

test1()

def test2():
    globals()['var2'] = 'qwerty'
    locals()['var2'] = 'uiop'
    print var2

test2()
```

What gets printed if you run the above code? To my surprise, it's:

```
asdf
ghjkl
qwerty
```

The first test behaves as I'd expect - the lookup in globals finds the value assigned outside the function, and the lookup in locals finds the value assigned locally. The second test is the surprising one - even though we've assigned a value in globals and a value in locals, locally referring to the variable by name finds the value we place in the *globals* dictionary, not the locals one.

Comment: The `locals()` fact you discovered is the reason that the docs say not to edit `locals()`.

Comment: @DSM Thanks, I missed that line in the docs when I skimmed them. I've updated my answer to reflect your observation.